# All items are not displayed properly while using UICollectionView grid view

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in `xcode4.2` and `IOS6`

I am using `UICollectionView` to display item in grid view.
I want to display items in 3x3 format but currently have 15 items so items should be displayed in following way

```
Page 1

Item1 Item2 Item3

Item4 Item5 Item6

Item7 Item8 Item9

Page 2

Item10 Item11 Item12

Item13 Item14 Item15

Here page 1 should be displayed default while page 2 on screen swiping

But currently these are displayed in following way

Page 1

Item1 Item4 Item7

Item2 Item5 Item8 

Item3 Item6 Item9

Page 2

Item7 Item10 Item13

Item8 Item11 Item14

Item9 Item12 Item15
```

It seems that UICollectionView arranges items vertically not horizontally.
Can you please help to resolve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Implemented by selecting direction horizontal and arranged the item left to right dynamically.
By default Items are arranged top to bottom, I changed the item according to index number so items looks like arranging left to right and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scroll direction to horizontal. Under attribute inspector there's an option to change scroll direction. Change it to horizontal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried it but no success.
If we select direction horizontal items are arranged top to bottom and if we select direction vertical then items are arranged left to right.
I want direction horizontal and arrangement left to right.